# CSS media queries not working for specific range as expected in chrome and Mozilla and didn't tested in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

Below example queries not working as expected and I tested in chrome(v74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and Mozilla(v66.0.2(64bit)) browsers.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px) {
  div.example {
    border: 8px solid black;
    background: yellow;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  div.example {
    border: 8px solid black;
    background: red;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  div.example {
    border: 8px solid black;
    background: green;
  }
}
```

For explanation purpose I will take below one

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  div.example {
    border: 8px solid black;
    background: green;
  }
}
```

Please look below screenshots for above media query:

Which is not working for 767px
[image]

Which is working for 766px
[image]

In the above media query not styling my `div.example` selector at `767px` screen size instead it styling below `767px` screen size.

In generally the above css snippet should work `767px` and `less then 767px` to`480px & above 480px` screen size.

But, above css snippet is working `less then 767px` to `480px & above 480px` screen size.

Similarly below queries also not working as expected

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px) {
  div.example {
    border: 8px solid black;
    background: yellow;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  div.example {
    border: 8px solid black;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

And finally I just manually look for which range of screen sizes are not working as expected then found for these ranges `981 to 991, 1181 to 1199, 761 to 767`.

Below css media queries working as expected but using different breakpoints.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 993px) {
  div.example {
    border: 8px solid black;
    background: yellow;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 769px) {
  div.example {
    border: 8px solid black;
    background: red;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  div.example {
    border: 8px solid black;
    background: green;
  }
}
```

Working for specific media breakpoints link - https://codepen.io/rag7s/pen/PvrREx

Not Working for specific media breakpoints link - https://codepen.io/rag7s/pen/pmXLpv

Comment: @Mr Lister this should be better called `CSS pixel` instead of just `pixel` to distinguish from `hardware pixel`

Comment: Oh, I see in the added screenshots that there is indeed a problem at your end. Can't reproduce with the provided codepens though; both work as expected on my machine.

Comment: Both your codepens seem to work fine. Maybe your window is zoomed a bit?

Comment: @MrLister Actually its working for all resolution except if you mention any number between these `981 to 991, 1181 to 1199, 761 to 767` ranges  in the place of `AAA`  in this media query  ``  @media screen and (max-width: AAApx) and (min-width: 480px) ``  its not working but working below that range. for example if I mention `981px` in query its working for `980px` and below but not working.

Comment: @KeesHak No its not zoomed.

Comment: Does this issue still occur when you resize the window manually instead of using the devices toolbar?

Comment: @KeesHak Yes it occurs when resize the window

Comment: @MrLister  Just now I checked with other system its working fine. I think these browsers wont work as expected for the particular range as I mentioned earlier in high resolution machines.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue? It happens at https://www.bbva.es/en/personas.html for me

Comment: Yess I solved by adding decimal for example @media (max-width:767.98px) and (min-width:478px}{ your css... }

Answer (score 1):

Check Now

```
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    div.example {
        border: 8px solid black;
        background: yellow;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    div.example {
        border: 8px solid black;
        background: red;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    div.example {
        border: 8px solid black;
        background: green;
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQVaxy

Comment: This one as same issue as I mentioned in Question description.